# Matchstick rearrangement: Zero to Hero

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking, matches

Below is an expression that has a value of 0.

How can you move only three matchsticks for the resulting value to be 49?

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Moving the left, middle and right matchstick you can make $49$...

> [image]
>
> ... as **XLIX** is $49$ in [Roman numerals](https://roman-numerals.info/49)!

Answer (score 37):

> How about LI - I - I, moving only two matchsticks?
>
>  [image]
>
> **LI - I - I** is $51 - 1 - 1$ which is $49$ in roman numerals.

Comment: If you would like I could add an image?

Comment: Added, no problem! :) Very clever answer to find it in just two matches

Answer (score 8):

My solution is rather strightforward:

> [image: 49]

Comment: Simple but effective!

Answer (score 6):

> Firstly orient your perspective by rotating the image a quarter turn clockwise (or equivalently, your vision a quarter turn anti-clockwise). Stand one of the lower four matches up to the right of the top 3 matches such that it represents a "0" shape, as viewed head-on. The move two of the lower three matches into a "- 1" configuration. Your movements should yield "50 - 1" which is indeed 49. The remaining match below the expression is just for emphasis or whatever. [image]

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch to use the top of a matchstick as a zero, but good lateral thinking anyway. Gave you a +1

Comment: How is the left bit supposed to be 50?

Comment: The first 3 matches are a "5" and the next matchstick head represents a "0"

Answer (score 5):

It's definitely not the intended solution, but you could move it like this...

> [image: ASCII!]
>
>  Simply put, this is using the fact that H in ASCII has the hex value of 48. Therefore, H+1 would be 49 in hex. Note that the faded matchstick is "moved" off the field entirely.
>
>
>  Note that other such solutions can be achieved - for example, "1" has the ASCII value of 49 (in decimal), and therefore simply tilting the middle matchstick so it becomes 1/1/1/1 makes it equal to 1, which is 49 in ASCII.

Another approach bends the rules a bit, but it's fun...

> [image]
>
>  This is 7^2 = 49 in roman numerals. Here, I've broken one of the matchsticks while moving it. Like I said, it's bending the rules (and a matchstick)...

Comment: Glen you definitely "Bended" the rules (see what i did there?)

Comment: @Dcybroz - hate to "break" it to you, but I already made that joke in the answer itself. :P

Comment: oh "snap!" i saw that. (:

Answer (score 4):

> - Each vertical matchstick equals -24.5
>  - Each tilted matchstick is a multiplication
>  - Each horizontal matchstick is a subtraction
>
> `|/|—|/|`
>
> resolves to :
>
> `-24.5 × -24.5 - -24.5 × -24.5 = 0`
>
> Moving 2 matchsticks like so :
>
> `|—|—|—|`
>
> resolves to :
>
> `-24.5 - -24.5 - -24.5 - -24.5 = 49`

Answer (score 2):

> Had to disappear a matchstick to make it work, but... (dodgy times symbol too)
>  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the fancy-clean edit :)